# How to exclude servlet-api-2.4 in groovy

Tags: groovy, jetty

I want to use jetty 9 (with servlet api 3.1) in my groovy 2.4 application. But groovy 2.4 comes with bundled servlet-api-2.4.jar. This causes errors, such as

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse.getStatus()I
```

I've tried grabbing javax.servlet-api version 3.1.0 via grapes but to no avail. Apparently, groovy's servlet-api jar overrides grape.

How can I do this?

Full code which throws the above error upon hitting the endpoint with a request:

```
@Grab(group="javax.servlet", module="javax.servlet-api", version="3.1.0", force=true)
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import javax.servlet.ServletException

@Grab(group="org.eclipse.jetty", module="jetty-servlet", version="9.4.8.v20171121")
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler

@Grab(group="org.eclipse.jetty", module="jetty-server", version="9.4.8.v20171121")
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server


public class WebHookServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
        def msg = slurper.parse(req.inputStream)

        // Do something with the message

        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT)
    }
}

Server server = new Server(8080)
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(server, "/ws", ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS)
context.addServlet(WebHookServlet.class, "/webhook")
server.start()
server.join()
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include your project build files.  This will help identify what's going on.  (There's been many changes to the coordinates for the servlet-api over the years)

Comment: Hi @JoakimErdfelt, I've added a small example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy>2.5 upgraded the servlet api to 3.0.1 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-7899

Not sure about the difference between 3.0.1 and 3.1 which jetty 9 uses but after a couple of brief tests, it seems to work OK.

Answer (score 0):

Try just adding ...

```java
@GrabExclude("javax.servlet:servlet-api")
```

That should exclude the default (older) coordinates/location for the Servlet 2.x series of dependencies.

But there are many other locations for Servlet 2.5 as well.
Try listing your dependencies on the command line, look for other coordinate locations  `<groupId>:<artifactId>` (without version) to see where the problem could be coming from.